# Display message if array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm displaying favorites from `localStorage` on a page and I'd like to display a message for people that don't have any favorites yet.
This is the `div` that displays the list which I'd like to repurpose to display the message below when there are no favorites:

```html
<div id='favorites'></div>
```

And here is the **JavaScript** that normally shows the favorites:

```js
var options = Array.apply(0, new Array(localStorage.length)).map(function (o, i){
    return localStorage.key(i);
});

function makeUL() {
    var LIs = '';
    var noFavs = 'Hmm, you must\'ve not favorited anything yet. Maybe you\'ll like <a href="#random-page" onclick="runme()" class="squiggly--url">this one</a>.';
    var len = options.length;

    if (len === 0) {
        document.getElementById('nofavorites').innerHTML = noFavs; 
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            LIs += '<li>' + options[i] + '</li>';
        }
        return '<ul>' + LIs + '</ul>';
    }
}

document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = makeUL();
```

Right now it just shows `undefined`.

Comment: You are putting the message into `'nofavorites'`. That should be `'favorites'`.

Comment: You put the return value of your function `makeUL()` into the container. If no options are given, the functions does not return anything aka `undefined`, which is then displayed in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `makeUL` function doesn't return any value when there's no element in the `options` array.

You'll have to choose between: updating your element inside your function
OR getting the value to insert inside your HTML element returned by your function. But you shouldn't do both.

You might want to change your code into something like this?

```
var options = Array.apply(0, new Array(localStorage.length)).map(function (o, i) {
    return localStorage.key(i);
});

function makeUL() {
    var LIs = '';
    var noFavs = 'Hmm, you must\'ve not favorited anything yet. Maybe you\'ll like <a href="#random-page" onclick="runme()" class="squiggly--url">this one</a>.';
    var len = options.length;
    if (len === 0) {
        document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = noFavs; 
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            LIs += '<li>' + options[i] + '</li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = '<ul>' + LIs + '</ul>'; 
    }
}

makeUL();
```

*Plus, you're targeting a `nofavorites` element that doesn't exist in your example.*

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The `nofavorites` was some code I tried just before posting, I seem to have forgotten to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This is in your html:

```html
<div id='favorites'></div>
<div id='nofavorites'></div>
```

Your javascript:

```js
var options = Array.apply(0, new Array(localStorage.length)).map(function (o, i){
    return localStorage.key(i);
});

function loadFavoriteHTML() {
    var favoriteHtml = '';
    var noFavs = 'Hmm, you must\'ve not favorited anything yet. Maybe you\'ll like <a href="#random-page" onclick="runme()" class="squiggly--url">this one</a>.';
    var len = options.length;

    // Clear html lists
    document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = ''; 
    document.getElementById('nofavorites').innerHTML = ''; 

    if (len === 0) {
        document.getElementById('nofavorites').innerHTML = noFavs; 
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            favoriteHtml+= '<li>' + options[i] + '</li>';
        }
        var ulHtml= '<ul>' + favoriteHtml+ '</ul>';
        document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = ulHtml;
    }
}

loadFavoriteHTML();
```

Your code is show `undefine` because when you dont have favorites list you dont return anything in you `makeUI` function, and by default the return value is undefined in a function if you dont have return.

I changed your code to set the UI in the function because you edit 2 different div. there is others way to do it. this is a one way.